# Flash H264 Encoding. Black screen

Tags: flash, h.264

My flash publisher has at least the 11.2 version and it uses the recently implemented by adobe feature - h264 encoding. By publisher I am implying the simplest flash application that makes the rtmp connection to the FMS server, creates a new NetStream object, attaches the camera stream to it and applies the h264 encoding like is showed below:

```
var h264Settings:H264VideoStreamSettings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();
h264Settings.setProfileLevel(H264Profile.MAIN, H264Level.LEVEL_3_1);
h264Settings.setKeyFrameInterval(15);
h264Settings.setQuality(0, 90);
h264Settings.setMode(480, 360, 15);

myStream.videoStreamSettings = h264Settings;
```

The video quality is really nice on the consumer side. The consumer application is the simplest app as well: it makes the rtmp connection and gets an access to the stream  by its name. The flash version on the consumer side >= 11.2 primarily.

So far, so good. 90% consumers are able to see the video playback; however, in some cases only black screen shows. I did try to find out what may cause the problem with no luck.

I tried to specify the bufferTime > 1, wmode="window" and wmode="direct", different browsers etc.

I do have a few following questions:

1. What may cause the problem and what is the possible workaround/solution?
2. Is there a change to get an event when the real picture is up?
3. I have found the VP6VideoStreamSettings class in the flash.media package, but there is not too much information what I can to do with it. Also, it is available as 'Addin'. What does it mean? Does anybody have any experience with it?

All your comments are really appreciated.

Comment: This is happening to me occasionally as well. Seems to happen on Windows environments in particular. Sometimes the video will not come through the NetStream to the subscribing SWF. The video attaches fine to a local video element and the audio comes through fine but not video. It seems intermittent, even on the same environment. It will work one time and then not the next. The NetStream info for the publishing SWF will show that it's sending video but the subscriber will show that no video is coming through.

Did you ever find an answer for this?